# How to implement voice chat in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, chat, voice, asyncsocket

I have made a simple chat application using AsyncSocket class where client nodes can send message to each other via chat server application. 
I want to integrate voice chat functionality in it but I am not getting any material over net which can show me correct direction to move on.

Can anyone suggest me some useful link or idea which can help me in its initiation??

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: Hi all, As I am beginner for implementing it , I analyzed SIP protocol. I have got some basic idea about how it works but still hanged on finding any suitable method or mechanism through which I can do it!

Can anyone suggest some??

Answer (score 2):

You can use GameKit, it has Voice chat support.

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries which implement SIP et al., like PJSIP, Sofia, etc. There are a few applications I know of that embed such libraries to do most of the work for them.

Of course, this assumes you wish to implement SIP.

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement Voice Chat over bluetooth using GameKit framework. If you want to see how it works please visit http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43756

Thanks